# How do I ensure an animation is complete before initializing another function or animation?

Tags: javascript, function, animation, raphael, settimeout

so here, I have a sequence of animations using Raphael:

1. fade in curve
2. fade in ball 1
3. animate ball 1
4. fade in ball 2
5. animate ball 2

however, with my code, steps 4-5 are initiated WHILE the steps 2-3 are still animating. How do I ensure steps 4 and 5 are initiated after the animations of 1-3 are complete? I've tried using setTimeout on my second function (ball2), but no luck.

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnQtW/) or here:

```
Raphael("bounce", 640, 480, function () {
               var r = this,
                p = r.path("M0,77.255c0,0,269.393,37.431,412.96,247.653 c0,0,95.883-149.719,226.632-153.309").attr({stroke: "#666", opacity: 0, "stroke-width": 1}),
                len = p.getTotalLength(),
            e = r.circle(0, 0, 7).attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#000", opacity:0}).onAnimation(function () {
                    var t = this.attr("transform");
                });
             f = r.circle(0, 0, 7).attr({stroke: "none", fill: "#000",opacity:0}).onAnimation(function () {
                    var t = this.attr("transform");
               });
            r.customAttributes.along = function (v) {
                var point = p.getPointAtLength(v * len);
                return {
                    transform: "t" + [point.x, point.y] + "r" + point.alpha
                };
            };
            e.attr({along: 0});
            f.attr({along: 0});

            var rotateAlongThePath = true;
            function fadecurve(ca,ba,aa,ab){
                ca.animate({opacity:1},500);
                setTimeout(function(){fadeball(ba,aa,ab);
                },1000);
            }
            function fadeball(ba,aa,ab) {
                   ba.animate({opacity:1},400);
                   setTimeout(function(){run(ba, aa,ab);
                   },1000);
            }
            function run(ba,aa,ab) {
                   ba.animate({along: aa}, ab, ">", function () {
                    ba.attr({along: aa});
                });
            }
            function startbounce() {
                fadecurve(p,e,.9,400),
                setTimeout(function(){fadeball(f,.8,400);
                    },1000);
            }
            startbounce();
        }); ​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Raphael's documentation, the animate method takes a callback method as it's fourth argument.   That method could be used to initiate the next animation in your sequence (or after the third animation).

```
    function fadecurve(ca,ba,aa,ab){
        ca.animate({opacity:1},500,,function(){fadeball(ba,aa,ab);});
    }
```

For example.